# Menu position for skin modifier resizing (Ctrl + A)

Tags: modifiers, interface

`Ctrl + A` allows you to resize vertices with skin modifiers applied.
You can also search for `skin resize` in f3.
But I didn't find this feature in the top menu.
[image]
Do you know the menu location for this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't, but you can access the x and y sizes from the Tool panel > Transform > Radius X/Y. You have to be in **edit mode**, in **vertex select mode** and you have to **select at least one vertex**.

You can't use the proportional editing that way though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. There is no great inconvenience in using skin resize.
However, I could also find object transforms and b-bones transforms in the top menu, so I expected skin resizing in the top menu.
I think this is a minor case of inconsistent UI.